# Chatters on clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do I stop people in my clan from chatting all the time? I don't want to boot them. I just need them to stop always talking. I have asked them to stop.

Comment: Chatting in CoC is a good thing. It means that your members are active. If you're worried about troop donation requests falling too far before being filled, then tell them that they need to donate more often or will be booted.

Comment: I've never played Clash of Clans so i might not be the best guy to give you an answer, but if what really bothers you it that you get notifications each times, you should be able to turn of notifications from that application in your phone's settings.

Comment: Bird956 and Glen make a good point. Is it the notifications that are causing issues? Or is it the donations? If you could give us a bit more information as to *why* you want them to stop, we should be able to help a bit more.

Comment: Is it just general Chatter in the Clan Reversed Chat Room? is so since you haven't booted them i'd assume it mean their chatter is not totally uncultured which is more i can say for Global ("you a girl?" "how old are you" "give us your kik" "join free elder" "[INSERT BEGGING TO JOIN BLACK+ PLAYER'S CLAN]", "[INSERT POINTLESS SPAM]).

Comment: I play COC a lot, and there is no way to mute players in your clan. IF Supercell adds that in an update, I will keep you posted. Also, there are no alerts/notifications on your phones for 'general chat'

Comment: I would personally rather have a clan chat full of chat than not. That would be an indication that the group is active and is getting along well. Now if what they are talking about turns more around bullying or talking bad of other players in the clan, then it's an issue and you can step in. Otherwise, what exactly is the problem with them chatting all the time?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry friend, but there is no way to stop 'pointless chatter' in the clan chat. Well, if you DON'T want pointless chatter, why do you have a clan in the first place is the question? It kinda defeats the purpose. All that to say, you can't stop the chatter in your clan chat without booting the members.